# How to style another object in when a user hover object in css

Tags: html, css

I want to style an object 2 when the user hovers object 1 in css. For Example:

```
<style>
.object1:Hover then style object2{
Styling of object2 Goes Here
}
</style>
```

how can i do that

Comment: Unless the two items are related (parent/descendant) or siblings you usually can't do that with CSS. If you explain more, and show us what you are trying to do we can help further. At the moment, **it's not clear**

Comment: I've added a comprehensive answer that explains the possible variations in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, as long as the html element 1 and 2 fulfill some conditions:

1. Object 1 has to come **before** Object 2 in your markup *(as you
   cannot go "up" or "back" in css selectors)*.
2. Object 2 has to be reachable by a css selector from Object 1's perspective *(again, you cannot go "up" or "back" in css
   selectors)*, that means that Object 2 cannot for example be in a
   parent context of Object 1 (which would also violate 1.).

---

Examples for such selectors:

## 1. Child selector

```
.object1:hover .object2 { your css rules here }
```

works for an html structure, where `.object2` is a **child element** of `.object1`:

```
<div class="object1">
  <div class="object2">Some content</div>
</div>
```

---

## 2. Adjacent sibling selector

`.object1:hover + .object2 { your css rules here }`

works for the (one!) **immmediately following sibling** `.object2`:

```
 <div class="object1"></div
 <div class="object2">This will be affected.</div>
 <div class="object2">This will NOT be affected.</div>
```

---

## 3. All siblings selector

`.object1:hover ~ .object2 { your css rules here }`

will apply your style for **all** (possibly *many*!) sibling `.object2` (but just as `+` NOT for child `.object2`):

```
 <div class="object1">
     <div class="object2">This will NOT be affected.</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="object2">This will be affected.</div>
 
 <someElementWhichisNotAffected></someElementWhichisNotAffected>
 
 <p class="object2">This will be affected.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.div1:hover{
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.div1:hover ~ .div2{
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```